# Evento change en input type text disabled ,cuando es sólo receptor de información

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo en HTML el siguiente input

```
 <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="input-baseimponible" name="baseimponible" tabindex="8" value="0" maxlength="10" disabled>
 </div>
```

Este elemento sólo recibe información  desde el controller a través de un ajax y no ha de ser accesible al usuario porque los datos provienen de una tabla y por seguridad no deben cambiarse , según el siguiente código

```
$("#input-baseimponible").val( toFormat(base,2) );
```

La idea es detectar  el change al recibir los datos y enlazar con una function,he probado  el siguiente código

```
$("#input-baseimponible").change(function(e){
alert("ha cambiado");
});
```

Pero no funciona , creo que es debido a la propiedad disabled.
Gracias anticipadas

Comment: ¿Pero por qué quieres detectar el cambio en el input? Es decir, el usuario no va a poder editar ese input, por lo que por ese motivo no se lanzará el evento change. ¿Quieres que se lance cuando cambia el input por la petición ajax? ¿Y por qué no llamas a la función deseada cuando te llega la respuesta ajax en vez de usar change? De todas formas, si quieres seguir haciendo eso, prueba a cambiar la propiedad disabled por readonly. Un saludo.

Comment: El evento change se activa cuando el elemento deja de tener el foco, no ante cualquier pulsación... si no quieres que lo toquen simplemente ponlo en *sólo lectura*, como comenta @MarcN

Comment: @Marc N: Con readonly tampoco funciona , no detecta el change:¿Porqué quiero detectar el cambio en input? el programa funciona cuando el orden de entrada de datos es  albaranes  con su iva , tipo de irpf,.Pero si después de esto se quiere añadir otro albarán  no modifica el Irpf , que se calcula sobre la base imponible,, espero haberme explicado

Comment: no tiene mucho sentido si se actualiza via ajax tu ya sabes que ha cambiado. en el mismo ajax tu puedes tomar accion y realizar las tareas. o bien puedes hacer un trigger. $("#input-baseimponible").trigger("change") para que se ejecute el evento change. El evento change es cuando el usuario interactua sobre el input, no cuando parte del codigo actualiza por programación el valor.

Comment: @toto .funcionó tal y como debería hacerlo ; gracias por la aclaración sobre change es muy importante saberlo